# GAMS- uncontrolled set entered as constant

Tags: gams-math

Consider the following problem in GAMS. I have two disjoint sets:
`i`and `j`. These are proper subsets of a subset `k`, where the union of `i` and `j` exactly equal the elements of `k`. I wish to construct a new variable X(`k`) (for the proper subset), that is a concatenation of A(`i`) and B(`j`). Intuitively, I wish to declare:

```
parameter 
X(k);

X(k)=A(i)+B(j);
```

Of course, this operation is not legal as i and j do not conform. But the idea is to take the values from A(i) for the i elements of X(k), and the rest to be taken from B(j). Any help on this is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a perfect example for an implicit set definition. So, you can do the following:

```
Set
   k
   i(k<)    / i1*i3  /
$onMulti
   j(k<)    / j1*j3  /;
   
parameter X(k);
```

Check this for more information:

https://www.gams.com/32/docs/UG_SetDefinition.html#UG_SetDefinition_ImplicitSetDefinition

Comment: Thank you so much! What I had done before your answer was to declare first X(*). Apparently, this allowed me to declare X as being on undefined dimension. Then, I set X(i)=A(i)  and X(j)=B(j).   It seems like the reverse operation of the one you posted?

Comment: I guess, what you did worked somehow, but you lost the domain checking capability (see https://www.gams.com/32/docs/UG_SetDefinition.html#UG_SetDefinition_DomainChecking).